# Can Java Standard Edition Application run on Mobile Phone? How?

Tags: java

I have developed two java applications that I would like them to communicate: One on Computer and another on the Mobile, but I have used Java Standard Edition instead of J2ME Edition. Will it run on the mobile phone? And how do I do it?

Comment: [Software recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13856/is-there-an-app-that-runs-java-jar-files-on-android) describes a couple of java emulators you could use.

Comment: Is this an old, J2ME feature phone, or a newer Android phone? Or something else like a Windows phone or an iPhone?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Network is a heck of a problem here(Africa). Anyway, it's a Android phone. I'm using HUAWEI